# C Program using Gauss Elimination Method and Partial Pivoting to solve systems of linear algebraic equations

Tags: c

I have a C Program (below) which uses Gauss Elimination Method and Partial Pivoting to solve systems of linear algebraic equations. My friend told me that I should rewrite it. He told me to begin cycles **for** with 0 instead of 1. Unfortunately I am not in touch with him anymore so he can not explain to me why is his solution better. I tried to rewrite these cycles **for** but the program does not work right. Maybe it is need to rewrite just some of these cycles not all of them. Would you please explain this problem to me (I want this program to be perfect)?

Systems of linear algebraic equation looks like A*X=B. This program reads input from a file matrix.txt.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef double **Matrix;
typedef double *Row;
typedef double *Col;
typedef double Elem;

Matrix allocate_matrix(int n);
Col allocate_col(int n);
Row allocate_row(int n);
void free_matrix(Matrix M, int n);

void pivot_partial(Matrix A, Col S,Col B, int n);
void forward_elimination(Matrix A,Col B,int n);
Col back_substitution(Matrix A, Col B, int n);
Col scale_factor(Matrix A,int n);
void gauss(Matrix A, Col B, int n);

void swap_rows(Row *r1, Row*r2);
void print_matrix(Matrix M, int n, char * name);
void print_col(Col C, int n, char *name);
void print_row(Row R, int n, char *name);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *ifp;
 int n,i,j;
 Matrix A;
 Col B;
 if(argc < 2)
 {
  printf("\nInput filename not passed \n");
  exit(1);
 }

 ifp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

 if(ifp == NULL)
 {
  printf("\nCould not open file %s\n",argv[1]);
  exit(1);
 }
 fscanf(ifp,"%i",&n);
  printf("A * X = B\n");
 printf("\nDimension(A) = %i\n",n);

 A = allocate_matrix(n);
 for( i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
  for(j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
   fscanf(ifp,"%lf", &A[i][j]);

 B = allocate_col(n);

 for(j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
  fscanf(ifp,"%lf",&B[j]);
 fclose(ifp);


 print_matrix(A,n,"A");
 print_col(B,n,"B");

 gauss(A,B,n);

 free_matrix(A,n);
 free(B + 1);

 getchar();
 return 0;
}

void print_matrix(Matrix M, int n, char * name)
{
 int i,j;
 printf("\n[%s] = ",name);
 printf("\n\n");
 for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
 {
  for(j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
   printf("%6lG ",M[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
 }
}

void print_col(Col C, int n, char * name)
{
 int j;
 printf("\n[%s] = ",name);
 printf("\n\n");
 for(j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
  printf("%6lg\n",C[j]);

}

void print_row(Row R, int n, char * name)
{
 int i;
 printf("\n[%s] = ",name);
 for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
  printf("%6lg ",R[i]);
 printf("\n");
}

Matrix allocate_matrix(int n)
{
 Matrix A;
 int i,j;
 A = malloc(n * sizeof(Row));
 if(!A)
 {
  printf("\nError : Could not allocate 
                       memory for matrix\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 --A;

 for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
 {
  A[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(Elem));
  if(!A[i])
  {
   printf("\nError : Could not allocate 
                               memory for matrix\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  --A[i];
 }
 return A;
}

void free_matrix(Matrix M, int n)
{
 int i;
 for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
   free(M[i] + 1);
 free(M + 1);
}

Col allocate_col(int n)
{
 Col B;

 B = malloc(n * sizeof(Elem));

 if(!B)
 {
  printf("\nError : could not allocate 
                       memory\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 --B;
 return B;
}

Row allocate_row(int n)
{
 Row B;
 B = malloc(n * sizeof(Elem));
 if(!B)
 {
  printf("\nError : could not allocate
                       memory\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 --B;
 return B;
}

Col scale_factor(Matrix A, int n)
{
 int i,j;
 Col S ;
 S = allocate_col(n);

 for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
 {
  S[i] = A[i][1];
  for(j = 2; j <= n; ++j)
  {
   if(S[i] < fabs(A[i][j]))
       S[i] = fabs(A[i][j]);
  }

 }
 return S;

}

void pivot_partial(Matrix A, Col S,Col B, int n)
{
 int i,j;
 Elem temp;
 for(j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
 {
  for(i = j + 1; i <= n; ++i)
  {
   if(S[i] == 0)
   {
    if(B[i] == 0)
              printf("\nSystem doesnt
                                   have a unique solution");
    else
       printf("\nSystem is 
                                        inconsistent");
    exit(1);
   }
   if(fabs(A[i][j]/S[i])>fabs(A[j][j]/S[j]))
   {
    swap_rows(&A[i],&A[j]);
    temp = B[i];
    B[i] = B[j];
    B[j] = temp;
   }
  }

  if(A[j][j] == 0)
  {
   printf("\nSingular System Detected\n");
   exit(1);
  }
 }

}

void swap_rows(Row *r1, Row*r2)
{
 Row temp;
 temp = *r1;
 *r1 = *r2;
 *r2 = temp;
}

void forward_elimination(Matrix A,Col B,int n)
{
 int i,j,k;
 double m;

 for(k = 1; k <= n-1; ++k)
 {
  for(i = k + 1; i <= n; ++i)
  {
   m =  A[i][k] / A[k][k];
   for(j = k + 1; j <= n; ++j)
   {
    A[i][j] -= m * A[k][j];
    if(i == j && A[i][j] == 0)
    {
         printf("\nSingular 
                                        system detected");
         exit(1);
    }
   }
   B[i] -= m * B[k];
  }
 }
}

Col back_substitution(Matrix A, Col B, int n)
{
 int i,j;
 Elem sum;
 Col X = allocate_col(n);
 X[n] = B[n]/A[n][n];
 for(i = n - 1; i >= 1; --i)
 {
  sum = 0;
  for(j = i + 1; j <= n; ++j)
   sum += A[i][j] * X[j];
  X[i] = (B[i] - sum) / A[i][i];
 }
 return X;
}

void gauss(Matrix A, Col B, int n)
{
 int i,j;
 Col S, X;
 S = scale_factor(A,n);
 pivot_partial(A,S,B,n);
 forward_elimination(A,B,n);
 X = back_substitution(A,B,n);
 print_col(X,n,"X");

 free(S + 1);
 free(X + 1);
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Next step would be posting only the problematic code, don't expect us to analyze this much code and solve the problem for you.  Finally, indent with 4 spaces, not 1; this is hard to read.

Comment: Though it's probably not why your code is working the "trick" of decrementing a pointer to `malloc()`ed storage and then referencing the first value with pointer[1] has undefined behavior under the C standard. It will work most of the time, but you'll never know for sure.

Comment: **NOTE**: The indexing in many examples in *Numerical Recipes in C* is just **Plain Wrong** and invokes *Undefined Behavior* by attempt accessed of values outside of the declared bounds by indexing, e.g. `for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {...}`. The algorithms are usually correct, the indexing is just botched due to an imprecise translation from FORTRAN to C. (e.g. real number arrays start at `1` in FORTRAN by default, and `0` always in C)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are naturally indexed starting at 0, not 1.  So if you have a[5], you get five slots: a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4].  So the "first" element of array a is in a[0].

You got around this with a trick.  In your allocate functions, you decrement the pointer that is returned from malloc. This has the effect of shifting the array slots over by one.  So what a[1] would have referred to is now getting what is in a[0].  That allows you to use the for loops starting a 1 and going up to n.

While the existing code will probably work just fine on any normal system and compiler, it isn't standard C.  This is probably what your friend meant about rewriting the code.
If you are going to change it, remove the pointer decrements in the allocate functions, then
change the for loops to go from 0 to n-1 instead of 1 to n.

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++)
```

The for loops that don't go from 1 to n, you will have to examine the logic carefully to see if it is correct.  Remember, lowest array element is 0, greatest is n-1.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your code resemble a lot the style introduced (or presented - I don't know whether they have borrowed it) in ["Numerical Recipes in C"](http://www.nr.com/). I really love this book, I own the 1st (yellow) edition, but I have a strong critique to address regarding their idea to let the C syntax resemble Fortran's. The two languages are different and simply Fortran (especially from Fortran90) has a strong dynamic matrix oriented syntax, while C as a light, static, multidimensional syntax.

In particular the two odd points, that are in your code as in Numerical Recipes are:

1. minor: the "trick", as already pointed out by Gene, of offsetting the arrays to be able to count from 1 to N.
2. major horror: the idea of allocating a matrix as an array of vectors, to be able to use the syntax A[i][j] with dynamic multidimensional arrays.

I personally think that the problem has been surpassed with C++ (see MTL, matrix template library for example), with which you can present an almost arbitrary interface with an arbitrary efficient implementation.

However I believe that it is *wrong* to search for a "nice" syntax, when it is not an accepted language best practice (point 1)  and especially when it is not performance wise (point 2): using array of arrays means that you are accessing elements by dereferencing two times every time you access one element of the matrix!

IMHO, coming back to C, The correct way - and I often have adapted NR's algorithms to this idea - is that an 2D, M (rows) by N (columns) array must be dynamically allocated as:

```
float *A = (float*)malloc(M*N*sizeof(float));
```

And can be accessed both by rows (elements in a row are contiguous in memory, and after the last element of a row, there is the first element of the following row), counting from *zero*:

```
for(i=0; i<M; ++i) {
    for(j=0; j<N; ++j) {
        x = A[i*N + j];
        ...
    }
}
```

That's how it is more common for the C style: this is how static multidimensional arrays in C works, except for the syntax used to dereference the elements (note: one dereferencing per element).

However it is possible to use the same array "by column" (that's the typical Fortran memory layout):

```
for(j=0; j<N; ++j) {
    for(i=0; i<M; ++i) {
        x = A[i + j*M];
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that I have exchanged the two loops: for performance it's better - whenever possible - to perform the inner loop over contiguous elements (more cache friendly).

One more practical and very important reason to use this style is that optimized BLAS and LAPACK libraries (see [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), [libgoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GotoBLAS), [mkl](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl), [acml](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/)....) for C use both of these approaches (by rows and by columns), counting from 0, all the time.

To let your code be perfect, I would change the NR's style to a more C conformant style... I hope that's the meaning of the question, and of your friend's comment :)